# Найти делители числа

Tags: c#, .net

Практикуюсь на Codewars. Написал метод поиска делителей числа. Он проходитит все тесты, кроме Performance Random Test. Получил System.OutOfMemoryException. Что с этим можно сделать? Заранее, спасибо!

```
public static int[] Divisors(int n)
{
    int N = 0;
    int[] divisors = new int[n];
    for (int i = 2; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            divisors[i] = i;
            N++;
        }
    }

    int[] ar = new int[N];
    int j = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < divisors.Length; i++)
    {
        if (divisors[i] != 0)
        {
            ar[j] = divisors[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if (ar.Length == 0)
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
    return ar;
}
```

Comment: а что должен делать второй цикл тут?

Comment: покажите код как у Вас проходит рандом тест

Comment: `new int[n];` нет смысла в выделении сразу такого большого массива. В большинстве случаев количество делителей у числа намного меньше чем само значение числа.

Comment: наверное самое простое решение - использовать `List<int>` вместо массива. Это позволит уйти от второго цикла и от выделения огромного куска памяти одномоментно

Comment: Самая базовая оптимизация, рассмативать делители не до `n`, а до `n / 2`, а ещё лучше до квадратного корня из `n`. Ну и как вам написали, нет смысла хранить огромное количество нулей в первом массиве

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `List<int>` - лучше решение, когда вы не знаете, сколько будет элементов в коллекции.
2. Число не может делиться на что-то большее, чем половина этого числа (верно?), следовательно перебор уже можно вести только до `n / 2`
3. Еще круче, если перебор проводить только до квадратного корня числа, при этом добавляя и делитель и частное, так как от перестановки множителей местами произведение не меняется.

Но я думаю и то что я написал, можно еще улучшить. Это так, наивная реализация:

```cs
public static int[] Divisors(int n)
{
    List<int> divisors = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 2; i * i <= n; i++)
    {
        if (n % i == 0)
        {
            divisors.Add(i);
            if (i * i != n)
                divisors.Add(n / i);
        }
    }
    divisors.Sort(); // это для красивого вывода, но можно убрать в пользу производительности
    return divisors.ToArray();
}
```

Еще можно не делать `.ToArray()`, а сделать вот так

```cs
public static List<int> Divisors(int n)
{
    //...
    return divisors;
}
```

Но это зависит от того, обязательное у вас условие вернуть именно массив, или просто так получилось.

Comment: откуда эти n/2 взялись? Уже не первый раз попадаются. Достаточно проверять до квадратного корня, так как после него уже пары для делителей, которые уже были. Например для числа 100 нет смысла в проверке всех чисел до 50, достаточно проверить все числа до 10 (включительно)

Comment: @Grundy ты точно не путаешь с простыми числами? Потому что 100 еще и на 50 делится. Как мне в список делителей вывести 50, если я только до 10 проверил?

Comment: @aepot, если ты разделишь 100 на 2, получишь число 50, нет смысла проверять делится ли 100 на 50 чтобы получить 2

Comment: @Grundy обновил ответ.

Comment: +1, этот цикл красивее записать с условием `i*i <= n` так можно не думать об округлении.